# Python windows extensions vcvarsall.bat incorrect windows SDK registry key

Tags: python, windows, python-extensions

I am having a lot of trouble trying to build Python extensions on a particular machine. It has both VS2008 and VS2013 installed along with, what I believe to be, the correct C/C++ libraries, etc. I am also comparing two machines which have roughly the same software, and the `vcvarsall.bat` and `bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat` files are identical.

One difference I've noticed is that the two machines have different values for `:GetWindowsSdkDirHelper` from `bin\amd64\vcvarsamd64.bat`:

- Good: `C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\`
- "Bad": `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1A\`

What I've tried, based on [the various environment variables set by vcvarsall.bat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2ccy3wt%28v=vs.80%29.aspx):

- `SET LIB=C:\Program Files\\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\lib\x64`. This removes one error but I still get `error LINK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_QueryPerformanceCounter` plus 6 similar errors.
- I've tried setting `INCLUDE`, `LIB` and `LIBPATH`, but I still get the `LINK2019` errors.

So, I Have a couple questions:

1. Can I just change the registry key for `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SDKs\Windows` to the "good" path? If so, what impacts will this have?
2. Why this is a problem? Perhaps I installed the VS2008/VS2013 in a different order, could that be the issue?

Comment: Check if following registration key points to correct VC directory where vcvarsall.bat can be found. COMPUTER\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\Setup\VC. I do not know if this is specific to 64 bit